# Making my salads a little better

Tags: salad

I eat a lot of salads for lunch. It's not hard for them to taste bland because I don't use creamy dressings and try to use healthy greens.

Here is an example of a typical salad I make: Spring mix, tuna (sometimes mixed with a dash of mayo), cucumbers, dressed with a mix of olive oil and apple cider vinegar. Sometimes I will add avocado to this.

It works, I feel good after eating this, but i'd like to make this a bit tastier.

Comment: Hi mrtunes. As you phrased it, I think this question is off topic, and unanswerable. Without knowing how *you* define tastier, the only answer could be: (1) Define what "Tastier" means for you, (2) Put ingredients that make (1) happen. We don't know (1), so can't answer (2). If you could add qualifiers or tastes you want to achieve, it might become an answerable question.

Answer (score 1):

To make  salads "better":

- Add nuts or roasted pumpkins seeds to add some crunch.
- Use bitter greens (arugula, radicchio,, white endives...)
- Add some root vegetables (carrots, radish...)
- Add some fruits either fresh or dried.
- Make different type of dressing (asian, middle-eastern...)
- Use different kind of protein(I hate that word) use smoked salmon, chicken, flank steak...
- Add noodles (rice noodles, ramen...) or do a simple pasta salad.

Don't know if you already do this, but only put the dressing before eating the salad.
If wanting to use fruits or other "fragile" ingredients, try to pack them separatly and mix them up before eating to keep everything fresh